# Remove a key from list of hashes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, hash-map

Suppose my milestone is this:

```
milestones = [ {state: 'unavailable'}, {state: 'arrived'}, {state: 'completed'} ]
```

I want to remove all the `unavailable` state from the list of hashes except the last one. My function works pretty well but I need some help to re factor it even further, and will appreciate any comments you can give. Here my code:

```
def filter_milestones(milestones)
      track_unavailable = Set.new
      filtered_milestones = []
      total_length = milestones.length
      if total_length == 1
        filtered_milestones = milestones
      else
        milestones.each_with_index do |value, index|
          if value[:state] == 'unavailable' && index != total_length - 1
            track_unavailable.add index
          end
        end
        milestones.each_with_index do |value, index|
          unless track_unavailable.include? index
            filtered_milestones << value
          end
        end
      end
      filtered_milestones
    end
```

So if my input milestone is `[ {state: 'unavailable'}, {state: 'arrived'}, {state: 'completed'} ]` then the return will be `[ {state: 'arrived'}, {state: 'completed'} ]`.

Comment: "I want to remove all the unavailable state from the list of hashes except the last one." Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but your example doesn't correspond with this text. Unless you mean that you only want to keep `unavailable` if it is the last of the values? Please provide more examples.

Comment: Yes you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks overly complex. If I understood it correctly, you want to filter out all unavailable states except if it's the last element. A more declarative and idiomatic Ruby approach would be:

```
filtered_milestones = milestones.reject.with_index do |milestone, idx| 
  is_last_milestone = (idx == milestones.size - 1)
  milestone[:state] == "unavailable" && !is_last_milestone
end
```

Comment: what's the complexity of this solution ? My code is O(n)

Comment: @python It's O(n). Your code, however, is not necessarily O(n), as far as I can tell. I don't know the big-O for the nested `include?`. If it's straight up item-by-item searching (I doubt that), worst case would be O(n+n^2)

Comment: Since this is a Set the time complexity is O(1)

Comment: @python Right, sets use hashes as storage - wasn't sure about that. So yeah, O(n). You're still doing two loops, though, while tokland's doing one, so it'll outperform yours. They both scale linearly, but tokland's code still beats yours on speed - and certainly on readability

Comment: I am just confused, how does reject works in Ruby? I think deleting a value based on the index is an expensive operation O(n), and then you're iterating over the same object you're deleting. Do you mind explaining this part?

Comment: I saw the visualization from (here) [http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display] , and things are cleared now.

Comment: `reject` does not delete values in-place, returns a new array. It's like a negative `select`. It's O(n), using a index does not change that. It's like an `enumerate` in python.

Answer (score 2):

Tokland's solution is (as always) very nice an simple. Very straightforward: Remove any `unavailable` unless it's the last element.

I'd pick tokland's solution myself; this is just an alternative. Here the approach is:

1. Set the last hash aside (since you'll want to keep that regardless of state)
2. Remove `unavailable` from all the others
3. Put the last hash back

```
def filtered_milestones(milestones)
  return milestones.dup if milestones.count < 2
  *head, tail = milestones
  head.reject { |hash| hash[:state] == 'unavailable' } + [tail]
end
```

p.s. I'd also suggest using tokland's naming (*filtered* milestones), since it's all about the data you get back, not what's done to it. That applies even if you wrap it in a method, rather than just doing an assignment expression.